# jspm install materialize but 404 on materialize.js when it runs

Tags: aurelia, materialize, jspm

I am getting a 404 error on this on this get:

```
http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/Dogfalo/materialize@0.96.1.js
```

I have used jspm to install materialize, and it the package is there as expected.

However, there is no actual file named materialize@0.96.1.js in the Dogfalo directory.

Is there something else I should be doing to get this to work?

Comment: Something's not adding up - is there a `materialize@0.96.1` directory in your github/Dogfalo directory?  This should be straight-forward.

Comment: Indeed, there is no materialize@0.96.1.js. However there is in materialize@0.97.0 version, if you can use it instead.

Comment: @dfsq, you are correct.  After I changed version to 97, then all worked as expected.  Will accept as answer if you post as answer.

Comment: @GregGum how to install  materialize through jspm

Comment: Did you try the jspm command below from dfwq?  `jspm install materialize=github:Dogfalo/materialize@0.97.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn out that the structure of the materialize@0.96.1 is not fully consistent and indeed missing materialize@0.96.1.js file in the package base folder. Possible solution is to use next minor version materialize@0.97.0 which has proper structure.

To get newer version run

```
jspm install materialize=github:Dogfalo/materialize@0.97.0
```